# $c \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $g(x,y) = f(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $g(0,0) = c$ so that function$f(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

We have some questions regarding

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^4}&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

Is there a $c \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $g(x,y) = f(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $g(0,0) = c$ so that the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$? What would that $c$ be then?

I have difficulties understanding this question. (It came up in our exam). I thought that since $f(x,y)$ is continuous already, we could just say that $c = 1$, but maybe I'm missing the point.

Any clue or clarification is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, $g(x,0)=0$. Therefore, the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}g(x,y)$, if it exists, is equal to $0$. So, if $c\ne0$, then $g$ cannot possibly be continuous at $(0,0)$. And if $c=0$, then $g=f$, which *is* continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you. If $g$ was continuous partially differentiable on $\mathbb{R^2}$, can we say anything about the total differentiability of $g$?

Comment: If $c\ne0$, then $g$ isn't even continuous at $(0,0)$. And if $c=0$, then $g(y,y)=\frac{|y|}{1+y^2}$, which is not differentiable. Therefore, there is no way that $g$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.